# Python Post Request returns 422 error for following post request

Tags: python, post, request

I am trying to execute a simple POST request in python however I am getting error 422 in response. What would be the proper way to execute this request?

```
formData = {'authenticity_token': 'SECRET KEY', 'price': '100', 'button': ''}
x = requests.post('https://theshownation.com/mlb20/items/cfbe0f33f88e0a053237ad6205530602/create_buy_order', params=formData)
print(x)
```

Comment: It seems like the the page doesn't exist

Comment: I am not able to see any such link for create_buy_order. I guess you may need to login first. I am not sure about `authenticity token` too as it changes everytime you open.